# How do I fix undefined reference to _imp__*?

Tags: c, gcc, dll, mingw

I'm trying to compile something that depends on gtkspell, which
depends on enchant, under MinGW.  I'm getting errors like
  `gtkspell/gtkspell.c:757: undefined reference to '_imp__enchant_broker_init'`
I suspect this is either due to the fact that I'm trying to link
againt a {static,dynamic} library when I should be linking against the
other one, or because there's only one underscore before the imp and
there should be two;  I get

```
$ objdump -t /d/opt/enchant-1.6.0/lib/libenchant.a | grep enchant_broker_init
[ 85](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00002ac0 _enchant_broker_init
```

and

```
$ objdump -t /d/opt/enchant-1.6.0/lib/libenchant.dll.a | grep enchant_broker_init
[  6](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 _enchant_broker_init
[  7](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __imp__enchant_broker_init
```

The internet
(http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2007-January/013975.html)
suggests that the imp mangling comes from

```
_declspec(dll{import,export})
```

though enchant seems to use

```
__declspec(dll{import,export})
```

, and commenting out the relevant lines in enchant.h makes gtkspell.c
request `enchant_broker_init` rather than `_imp__enchant_broker_init`, but
doesn't change the symbols that show up in libenchant.  Is there a way
to make gcc not mangle the names, or does anyone have ideas about what
might be going wrong/how to fix it?

Here's a minimal example that reproduces the problem on my system:

If I have a file enchanttest1.c with contents

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <enchant.h>

int main()
{
#ifdef ENCHANT_MODULE_EXPORT
    printf("\nEnchant found\n");
#else
    printf("\nEnchant not found\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

and a file enchanttest2.c with contents

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <enchant.h>

int main()
{
    EnchantBroker *b = enchant_broker_init();
#ifdef ENCHANT_MODULE_EXPORT
    printf("\nEnchant found\n");
#else
    printf("\nEnchant not found\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

then

```
gcc enchanttest1.c `pkg-config --cflags enchant` && ./a.exe
```

gives `Enchant found` but

```
gcc enchanttest2.c `pkg-config --cflags enchant` && ./a.exe
```

gives

```
C:\Users\JASONG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyDLptc.o:testenchant.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_imp__enchant_broker_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This is a stupid suggestion, but are you making sure you're invoking C (not C++) compilation? You may be experiencing subtle name mangling ridiculousness?

Comment: The `enchant.h` file wraps everything in 

    `#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif`

so I don't think that's the problem.  I've also since added a minimal example where I'm pretty sure I'm invoking C compilation.

Comment: As a note for followers, when I got this it was because the "dependency library" was defined with __declspec(dllimport), even though it was a static compile.  So removing that fixed it up, see http://betterlogic.com/roger/2012/09/libflite-cross-compile-woe/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to fix my minimal example is to add `--libs` after `--cflags`; gcc couldn't find the library to link against.

I was able to fix the problem that I was running in to with the more complicated code that I was originally trying to compile (gummi (https://gummi.app/)) by passing `LDFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkspell-2.0 enchant)"  CFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkspell-2.0 enchant)"` to the configure script; the problem seems to have been that the arguments to gcc were passed in the wrong order, and it couldn't find enchant when it was trying to link gtkspell.

Comment: Ugh...I just ran into this, making a MinGW port of some legacy code. I can't believe gcc still has this link-order dependency issue, after all these years.

Comment: The `dev.midnightcoding.org` URL in this post is now outdated. I *think* the current URL is https://gummi.app/ - could someone familiar with Gummi check this and make the edit if so?

Comment: Yes, it's the same project, https://web.archive.org/web/20140702194619/http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi shows the author is Alexander van der Mey, which is the same as the github linked to by gummi.app.  I'll fix my answer